# How to terminate main program when thread ends? Still getting waiting for process to detach in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-multithreading

I am having a main program which is defined like this:

main.py

```
def main():

try:
    registry.start_server()
except:
    print("Shutting down the program")
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

registry.start_server() is the method in another module which looks like this:

```
def start_server():
    t_server = threading.Thread(target=server.start)
    t_server.start()
    try:
        t_server.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Error")
        raise ValueError

finally:
    fp.close()
```

server.start is the method in another module which does some listening work in a **while(True)** manner. I am not sure how to stop the whole program when clicking Stop in PyCharm which is Ctrl + C (Signal). I tried with Event but without success. I get to the main.py by raising an exception when the signal gets caught but that does not terminate the whole program. It shows *Waiting for program to detach*. The only way is to use SIGKILL. I don't understand where does the program keeps hanging? I have also tried calling sys.exit(0) when the signal gets caught and creating the thread as Deamon but that didnt help either.

**EDIT**
*While True method in another module*

```
def start(self, event):

 try:
        while True:
            if event.is_set():
                if self.pubsub.channels:
                    print("It enters here")
                    message = self.pubsub.get_message(True)
                    if message:
                          . 
                          .
                          .
           else:
                return
```

Comment: *"work in a while(True) manner"*: How did you expect to **end** this infinit loop? Read [close a thread on multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686996/7414759)

Comment: It breaks out of while loop now, however I am still not able to catch KeyboardInterrupt Exception. I have read all the answers on SO which use thread.join or signal.pause() but that will block main thread (it get stuck on checking if the event.is_set() in the while loop). I have also tried adding atexit and setting event.clear and sys.exit(0) but I still get KI Exception

Comment: Try this approach [KeyboardInterrupt multiple threads at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50886974/7414759)

Comment: I don't understand why the mehtod which is called in another thread is not being executed normally when I have any kind of waiting process inside main thread. e.g t.join() or time.sleep(1) after t.start(). It immediately returns to the main thread and ignores the method in another thread.

Comment: *"I don't understand why"*: **Without** a [mcve] I couldn't tell anything?

Comment: See my edit. Whenever I put any while loop after t_server.start() this thread has the control and "It enteres here" is never printed. The *if event_is_set()* get executed but the program won't continue to work normally and print next statement

Comment: I was trying to put the main thread to sleep or deamon but since it does not have anything to do deamon mode is not very useful. It terminates immediately. I would like to catch Keyboard Interrupt and then set *event.clear()* and *t_server.join()*, but it seems impossible to do it

Comment: **BAD**: if `def self(...` is part of a `class xy(Thread)`. **BAD**: `try: ... except ...` enclosing a bunch of code lines. We have reached end of comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188954/discussion-between-pegasus-thorn-and-stovfl).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, all you need to do is:

1. let the child-thread exit, and
2. let main thread join the child-thread.